# Best way to compare this simple ruby/rails Date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, time

I have an object that contains a date timestamp such as

```
      time = Sat, 06 Apr 2013 08:00:00 PDT -07:00
```

I am simply trying to compare the object time, to see if the date matches the day(month, day, year) tomorrow (not conerned with the time).  This check  will happen everyday.

I am trying things such as:

```
      time == Date.tomorrow
```

Comment: I'm not sure why that doesn't work for you. In my console it works fine and dandy..

Comment: @shuriu: it kind of works but because the timestamps are unlikely to be the same, you'll almost always get `false`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do:

```
time.to_date == Date.tomorrow
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Date.parse(time) == Date.tomorrow
```